# Filter nested list in a MongoDB collection

Tags: mongodb

I need to filter out with a condition 2nd level nested list inside mongo documents,
i need it to return all original fields and documents and only filter out the nested documents inside of it,
for example:

```
[{
  "_id": 1234,
  "outerDucumentName": "someName",
  "nestedList": [
    {
      "nestedId": 2222,
      "nestedNestedList": [
        {
          "nestedNestedId": 3333,
          "nestedType": 1
        },
        {
          "nestedNestedId": 4444,
          "nestedType": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": 4567,
  "outerDucumentName": "someOtherName",
  "nestedList": [
    {
      "nestedId": 5555,
      "nestedNestedList": [
        {
          "nestedNestedId": 6666,
          "nestedType": 1
        },
        {
          "nestedNestedId": 7777,
          "nestedType": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

to filter out nestedType = 2 nested documents so the result would be :

```
[{
  "_id": 1234,
  "outerDucumentName": "someName",
  "nestedList": [
    {
      "nestedId": 2222,
      "nestedNestedList": [
        {
          "nestedNestedId": 3333,
          "nestedType": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
},
{
  "_id": 4567,
  "outerDucumentName": "someOtherName",
  "nestedList": [
    {
      "nestedId": 5555,
      "nestedNestedList": [
        {
          "nestedNestedId": 6666,
          "nestedType": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}]
```

i've tried using $addField, $unwind, $unset, $set - but could not get the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Since it is double nested, one option is to use `$filter` inside `$map`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$set: {
      nestedList: {
        $map: {
          input: "$nestedList",
          as: "ns",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$ns",
              {nestedNestedList: {
                  $filter: {
                    input: "$$ns.nestedNestedList",
                    cond: {$ne: ["$$this.nestedType", outerDucumentName ]}
                  }
              }}
            ]
          }
        }
      }
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JBQcHruCnb4)

Comment: Great, Thanks! how would you change the query to filter according to some outer document value, for example this.nestedType = outerDucumentName ?

Comment: works great, Thanks! sorry i cannot upvote need to get 15 reputation first.